# how to extract Android_NDK_r11.zip on macos?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting .zip file after downloading it from this  [Location](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#download/) and when I tried to unzip it, it is giving me .tar.bz2 which is not fully extracted as per docs and other blogs. So please provide me steps to extract it from .zip to NDK folder.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the suffix of what you extracted is `.tar.bz2`, it actually is a directory - it seems to me like this just is a mishap/accident in how it was packaged. You can just rename the directory to remove the `.tar.bz2` suffix - it will work just fine either way.

Comment: I tried removing .tar.bz2 from the directory but it is not working for me. I am passing the location of the resulting folder in Appcelerator studio's prefernces which is not accepting this.

Comment: In case Appcelerator studio tries to look for some specific files in the NDK directory, it might not find all of them, apparently at least the `ndk-depends`, `ndk-gdb`, `ndk-stack` and `ndk-which` scripts are no longer available there, only `ndk-build`. I don't know about Appcelerator, but for plain compiling from command line using `ndk-build`, it should be just fine.

Comment: yes you are right those files are not there so how we can use this NDK with appcelerator studio. Also do I need any other tool to extract it properly. As per google docs they gave commands that support extraction from .bin so is there any workaround to get that .bin from the .zip

Comment: No, the instructions about .bin are just out of date. If you have a directory that contains `ndk-build` and the other directories like `build`, `platforms` and `toolchains`, you have extracted it correctly. Now there is nothing more to the question "how to extract it". If Appcelerator studio doesn't work with or detect this new NDK version, that is their issue to fix, which is unrelated to the question on how to extract it.

Comment: FWIW, NDK r11b was released a few days ago, which seems to fix a few issues about how files have been moved around - perhaps this fixes your issue as well?